# Why UIButton requires two clicks to change its image

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I am new to iOS app development using Swift 4. I used the code below to change the image of `button2` by running it in the iOS simulator:

```
 @IBAction func button2(_ sender: Any) {
     button2.setImage(UIImage(named: "wrong_answer"), for: .normal)
 }
```

However, `button2` was highlighted when I first click on it without changing its image. Then after the second click, the image has been changed in `button2`.

My question is why the image was not changed in `button2` after the first click?

What can I do to change the image after the first click instead of twice? Is this a bug in the iOS simulator of Xcode or it is normal?

Comment: i think it's simulator bug.your code is correct(please change sender from `Any` to `UIButton`)

Comment: That may because you have set image to normal state and the button must be in highlighted state. But do check that code on device.

Comment: @J.Doe i said i think. if you know the correct answer please post it because it's as you say basic

Comment: Notice that you call the button "sender" in the method. You need to update sender, not button2. This would be clearer if you updated sender to UIButton (which is what it is) instead of using Any.  See my answer below.

Comment: @J.Doe so please ask and try to answer and do not interrupt the community

Comment: Thank andesta, rptwsthi and Mozahler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's simulator bug. it worked on a real device
@IBAction func button2(_ sender: UIButton) {
     button2.setImage(UIImage(named: "wrong_answer"), for: .normal)
 }

Answer (score 2):

You probably have an issue related to `UIButton` states that is causing this problem. 
I don't think it is a simulator bug.
By the way, a good practice you should follow is to name the outlet different than the `@IBAction`. Let's say:

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
  button.setImage(UIImage(named: "image"), for: .normal)
}
```

Try this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  button.setImage(UIImage(named: "image"), for: .selected)
}

@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
  button.isSelected = !button.isSelected
}
```

And then the image will be updated automatically when you tap on the button. You can change it to `button.isSelected = true` if you want to keep the image after the first tap.

Answer (score 0):

Rename your method/action so it differs from the button/property.

Change Any to UIButton since you know its class.

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ buttonTapped: UIButton) {
  buttonTapped. button.isSelected = !button.isSelected
}
```

Make sure that you are receiving the button callbacks by declaring your view controller a UIButtonDelegate and set the button's delegate property to self.

Comment: Did you declare your view controller a UIButtonDelegate and set the button's delegate property to `self`?

Comment: Excellent. Glad you figured it out!